# "Цветут цветы" — тавтология?

Tags: стилистика, тавтология

Стоит ли избегать в тексте оборота "цветут цветы"? Является это тавтологией или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тавтология представляет собой лексическую ошибку, если употребление однокоренных слов не оправдано стилистическими целями и носит случайный характер: воедино соединить, станцевать танец, по-спортивному относиться к спорту, подтвердить утверждение. Это считается стилистической ошибкой. Но тавтология может быть и тонким риторическим приёмом, например, в литературе этот прием чрезвычайно употребителен. В былинах: "На Руси - то трава растет не по-старому, цветы цветут не по-прежнему... А видно Вольги живого нет...", в сказках: " Скоро сказка сказывается, да не скоро дело делается";сиднем сидеть, горе горькое.
 Не помню где, но видела и в современной лирике (не у Рубцова ли?): "Цветут цветы моей души".Ничего, смотрится. "Цвести" ведь слово многозначное, поэтому допускает такие сочетания: Цветы ещё цветут. Цветы уже отцвели.-оправдано.Цветут цветы в нашем саду - как-то не очень.Так что сами смотрите,  оправданно ли  стилистически сочетание.

Comment: >Цветут цветы в нашем саду - как-то не очень  

Не вижу "неоченности". Если и есть какая-то сложность, то фонетическая... "Цветут цветы в моем саду" - уже хоть в песню вставляй.

Comment: Почему же "Цветут цветы в нашем саду" как-то не очень. Цветы могут цвести - то есть находиться в состоянии цветения, а могут не цвести - например, когда не сезон. И вот когда они цветут, тогда вы и говорите "цветы цветут", а в остальное время они у вас там просто растут, не цветя.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже неоднократно заявлялось на этом форуме, тавтология — не всегда зло.     
Конечно, слова однокоренные, но слово *"цветут"* имеет смысл *"распускаются"* (или что-то вроде того), так что *"цветут цветы"* не тавтология.

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, это выражение вполне допустимо в речи, его использовали в своих произведениях Шмелёв, Розанов, Белый и другие мастера слова:  ***И еще раздражался: отчего вокруг меня не весело, не цветут цветы. (В. В. Розанов***)